# How do I configure pfsense as an outbound VPN client?

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunnel, pfsense

We use pfsense as a router/firewall. Because we're based in China, it is useful for us to have VPN access for all our internal clients. Instead of each individual client connecting to a VPN server stateside, I'd like to configure pfsense as a VPN client and have all the network traffic be routed through it.

Most of the posts I've seen regarding pfsense and VPN are concerning connecting to the LAN from outside; this is **not** what I want to do.

Another option would be for an SSH tunnel to be initiated on the pfsense box with the LAN traffic routed through it.

**How do I configure pfsense to be able to do either of these?** One huge caveat is that OpenVPN **cannot** be used. The solution I am looking for needs to use one of the other VPN protocols.

Comment: What VPN protocols can be used?

Comment: PPTP, L2TP, IPSec

Comment: If pfSense can't do it, would you consider an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

You configure openvpn client in pfsense.  Its under VPN->OPENVPN->Client.

The link below has an excellent walkthrough for it:

https://www.blackvpn.com/support/pfsense-with-openvpn/

Comment: I will fill in more detail here once I am back at my computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Grant. I added a caveat... I can't use OpenVPN. It gets blocked here.

Comment: After I configure OpenVPN client, then what can I do with it?

Comment: I agree that openvpn is probably the simplest (IPSec + L2TP are still broken under pfSense 2.1, IPSec by itself works well) - note that you can specify what port your openvpn client/server use (try tcp 1723 or  udp 500/5500 tcp 1701 -- those are pptp and IPSec/L2TP).